# How to compare different choices of different methods

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Suppose I have different methods, A, B and C. Suppose further I used these method to select me colour balls. Assume that I need to select three balls using each method. Assume that method A selected 2 reds balls and one green ball. Assume further that, both method B and C selected 3 green balls. Now, I would like to say that method A slect 2 balls different from the choise of method B and C.

> Method A selected two balls that are different from the balls selected by both method B and C.

Is my sentence clear and understandable. If not, how can I express my idea in a clear way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you haven't said how the balls are different. You would to express that it's their colour that's different. I would also put everything in the past tense (your sentence currently has one verb in the present tense). Last, if you say *method B and C* it could almost be interpreted as if those two methods were combined when they selected different balls—rather than making it clear that they *each* selected their own (and different) balls.

In short, this is how I would rephrase it:

> Method A selected two **differently coloured balls than those** selected by **either** method B **or** C.

However, that *might* also lead to some confusion. After all, all three methods *did* select at least one green ball. That sentence doesn't describe the exact results.

To be even more explicit, say exactly what happened—which requires more extensive rephrasing:

> Unlike either method B or C, which each selected three green balls, method A selected one green ball and two red balls.